# Java programming - cannot reveive input from getInput in word filtering code

Tags: java, string

I've been coding a while for an assignment but can't figure out how
to receive a string input from the user to have the sentences filtered by unicode.
When I try to run the code, the input prompt won't happen. What am I doing wrong?
Any advice is appreciated.

```
package deel1;

import java.util.*;

public class Deel1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    static String getInput() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String zin = "";

        System.out.println("Voer een zin in: ");
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            zin = scan.nextLine().trim();
        }

        if (zin.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Geen invoer!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return zin;
    }

    static String filterZin(String zin) {
        for (int groteLetters = 65; groteLetters <= 90; groteLetters++) {
            groteLetters = groteLetters + 32;
            char kleineLetterAlfabet = (char) groteLetters;
        }
        int specialeTekens1 = 33;
        int specialeTekens2 = 58;
        int specialeTekens3 = 91;
        if (specialeTekens1 <= 47 && specialeTekens2 <= 64 && specialeTekens3 <= 96) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Gefilterd: " + zin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Automatic method invocation is not a language feature yet. Till then you have to do it manually, from `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah, come on, nobody posted an answer?

As [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806359/java-programming-cannot-reveive-input-from-getinput-in-word-filtering-code/18806606#comment27735688_18806359), you never invoked the function!

```
//this method is the entry point
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // invoke getting input, store it in local variable
    String input = getInput();

    //invoke filtering method, store result in lcal variable
    String output = filterZin(input);


}
```

The `filterZin` method doesn't really do anything...

Bigger problem, that it is not even *valid*! The `filterZin` method is specified to have a String return type - and nothing gets returned. Add a return statement to the end, to get at least a syntactically correct method...

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a method getXYZ() which returns a String when called.
This is your method definition:

```
static String getInput() {
//your code
return someString;
}
```

This says, when you'll call this method at any point in the program, this method will return a String object.

Inside your main method:

```
String returnString = getInput();
```

This is called method calling or invocation. You will not receive something until you call for it.

Now, about your program asking for input from user.

Here's a simple code for that:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//This will create a chain for input from console
System.out.println("Enter a line:");
String userInput;
try{
userInput = br.readline();
}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```